# Поиск элемента в iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно найти элемент (ссылку ) во вложенной структуре iframe. Сколько там будет iframe неизвестно, возможна древовидная структура. Как это реализовать на JQuery или любым другим способом на JS?

Comment: А зачем его искать. Они все в **document.frames**

Comment: Просканируйте `document.links`, `document.frames[].links` и вложеные в frames frames

Comment: document.frames - возвращает undefinded, chrome 51.

Comment: а что за iframe? хотя бы с этого же сайта (домена)?

Answer (score 1):

Вот смотри:

```
$(function(){
   var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#someID").contents();
   //Теперь мы можем использовать find() для доступа к элементам iframe:
   //например
   iFrameDOM.find(".message").slideUp();
});
```

И дальше как на главной...

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю сколько там iframe и в каком из них находится моя ссылка. Нет ли какой-либо библиотеки, позволяющей автоматически проверить все вложенные iframe?

Comment: Что тебе мешает подсчитать все iframe на странице, и см помощью JQuery по ним бегать?